# How can i solve ""Need to upload logs" Error

Tags: kaa

this ERROR is when i try to sent data temperature from FIRST APP TUTORIAL

```
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO FirstKaaDemo - Sampled Temperature: 31
[pool-4-thread-147] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.logging.strategies.RecordCountLogUploadStrategy - Need to upload logs - current count: 147, threshold: 1
[Thread-2] INFO org.kaaproject.kaa.client.channel.impl.channels.DefaultOperationTcpChannel - Can't sync. Channel [default_operation_tcp_channel] is waiting for CONNACK message + KAASYNC message
```

Need to upload logs Need to upload logs Need to upload logs !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!????

Answer (score 0):

Please check your connection to the server and configuration of the Mongo DB Log Appender:

1. Ensure the Kaa host on Kaa Sandbox Management page is configured correctly. Ideally, you should change localhost (127.0.0.1) there to real IP address of the PC host you are running the Kaa Sandbox on.
2. Ensure the application PC host can reach the Kaa Sandbox IP address by the IP address configured on the Kaa Sandbox Management page (see item 1).
3. Ensure the Kaa SDK used for the application was downloaded after the change of the Kaa host on the Kaa Sandbox Management page.
4. Check your [MongoDB log appender](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Data-collection/MongoDB-log-appender/") configuration.

Comment: hi, i can't receive data to my mongodb when auth=true and and when i configure authentification user and passwrd,....!> transport_public_interface=***.***.***.***    >> please help